Can the edges of a complete digraph be partitioned into Hamiltonian paths such that the $i^{th}$ vertex in each path is distinct?
For $n \neq 3,5$, we can partition the edges of the complete digraph $K^*_n$ (with $n$ vertices and $n(n-1)$ edges) into $n$ Hamiltonian paths, per the answer here. Can it be done such that the $i^{th}$ vertex in each path is distinct?
For $n = 2^k$, the answer is yes:
Label the vertices $\{v_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ and the paths $\{P_{i,j}\}_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}$, with $P_{i,1} = v_i$. Then let $P_{i, j+1} = P_{i,\sigma^j(j)}$ where $\sigma = (1 \dots n) \in S_n$.

Edges are not reused: the edge from $P_{i, j}$ to $P_{i, j+1}$ corresponds to adding $j \pmod{n}$ to the index of the vertex, so they are distinct for each $j$ with $1 \leq j \leq n-1$; and the edge starts from $i$, so they are distinct for each $i$.
Vertices in $P_{\cdot, j}$ are distinct: $\sigma$ is bijective, so $\sigma^{\frac{1}{2}j(j+1)}$ is as well.
Vertices in $P_{i, \cdot}$ are distinct: suppose not, so that $P_{i,j} = P_{i,j'}$ for some $i,j,j'$ where $j < j'$. Then $\sigma^{\frac{1}{2}(j'(j'+1) - j(j+1))}(i) = i$, so $\frac{1}{2}(j'(j'+1) - j(j+1)) + i \equiv i \pmod{2^k}$. Then
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}(j'(j'+1) - j(j+1)) \equiv 0 &\pmod{2^k}\\
&\therefore j'(j'+1) - j(j+1) \equiv 0 &\pmod{2^{k+1}}\\
&\therefore j'^2-j^2+j'-j \equiv 0 &\pmod{2^{k+1}}\\
&\therefore (j'-j)(j'+j+1) \equiv 0 &\pmod{2^{k+1}}
\end{align}$$
The factors on the LHS have different parity as they differ by $2j+1$, but the product is divisible by $2^{k+1}$, so both factors are powers of 2. Thus the smaller must be 1, so $j' = j+1$. Thus $2j' \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{k+1}}$, so $j'\geq2^k$, a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

This proof, if correct, may be overcomplicated, but it's the best I have so far.
The original problem I'm working on is this, which I believe is equivalent (here the vertices correspond to people and the Hamiltonian paths correspond to the paths of each book):

You are organising a book exchange with $n$ people. Person $i$ starts with book $i$. Each month, everyone must give someone else their current book. You must give this book to someone to whom you have not yet given a book, and who has not yet had this book. Everyone must eventually read every book. Every month, everyone must have a book.


(I might be misunderstanding this) Per your linked problem, we need $ n \neq 4, 6$? So how does $ n = 2^2 $ work?

@CalvinLin Linked problem reached this conclusion: Hamiltonian cycle decomposition is impossible for $n=4,6$. Hamiltonian path decomposition exists for $K^_n$ iff Hamiltonian cycle decomposition exists for $K^_{n+1}$. So Hamiltonian path decomposition exists for $n \neq 3,5$.
